# Finite verbs / Do vs Be

Tags: modal-verbs, auxiliary-verbs, finite-verbs

Which is correct?

1. "You were always looking out for me. You always do."

or

1. "You were always looking out for me. You always are."

Answer (score 1):

Both expressions are correct.  They both mean almost the same thing. . . or exactly the same thing.  Both are truncated.  The first would be finished "You always do look our for me," and the second would go, "You always are looking out for me."

Comment: Right. Since _were always looking out for me_ starts with _be_, it can be used -- like the first auxiliary verb in any verb phrase can -- in the second sentence echo. However, that verb phrase also contains the verb phrase _look(ing) out for me_, and because there is an attachment ambiguity, the second sentence echo can refer to **that** verb phrase, too. And since there's no auxiliary verb, _Do_-support is required in the echo.